# Python Highscores w/ text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode

i am currently working on a text based game, and have run into a problem trying to make my last function, `highscore`.
My problem is this, i would like to make the function save my top five `scores` and save it to a text file, along with the player's `username`, and then be able to print this into my text based game.
I know this could be hard to do, but i would like it if the scores were saved in a text file, and not a `pickle` as i have seen suggested, as i would like to share the file with some friends.
Any help is appreciated,
Thanks, Tom.

edit:
I am comfortable opening the file for writing. my code included the `scores.sort` command, but i wasn't sure how to put 5 scores into the file, and have the 6th score deleted. Thanks for the help, Tom

Comment: It is not too hard to do; you just need to break the task down into steps and search your way through them. Have you opened the file for writing? Please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show where you are up to and try to be specific about what the issue is that you're struggling with.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! What are you using to store your high scores in Python? A class, a dictionary?

To simply write string content to a file you can do the following:

```
scores = [('username1', 123), ('username2', 456)]
with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:
    for username, score in scores:
        f.write('Username: {0}, Score: {1}\n'.format(username, score))
```

Comment: edit: The code works absolute wonders, thanks! Just a question, the new score seems to replace the old one even if it is lower. For example, i have a score of 15 and then get a score of 0, the file looks like this `Username: tom, Score: 0`

Comment: Do i need to open the file first and check if the new score is larger than the old one, and if so, how would i go about doing this?