# How do I make my highscore text file with only 5 highscores

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53299137/11001876 and it works so far but I'm not sure how to limit the highscores to only 5 with only the highest scores staying on the highscore text file. I've edited the code in the link to fit my program:

```
# Winning Code
  elif U1Score > U2Score:
    print(username1, "Won")
    highscores = open("highscores.txt", "r")
    highscores.close()
    with open('highscores.txt', 'w') as f:
      for username1, U1Score in scores:
        f.write('Username: {0}, Score: {1}\n'.format(username1, U1Score))
    highscores.close()
    highscores = open("highscores.txt", "r")
    print(highscores.read())
    highscores.close()
  else:
    print(username2, "Won")
    highscores = open("highscores.txt", "r")
    highscores.close()
    with open('highscores.txt', 'w') as f:
      for username2, U2Score in scores:
        f.write('Username: {0}, Score: {1}\n'.format(username2, U2Score))
    highscores.close()
    highscores = open("highscores.txt", "r")
    print(highscores.read())
    highscores.close()
```

However I'm still not sure how to limit the scores to 5 different scores and how to order them from highest to lowest. Thanks I'm new here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is to instead of printing the file.read() read the file by lines (cause the delimiter you used is line) and then print just 5 lines.

Something like that maybe:

```
f = open("highscores.txt", "r")
highscores_lines = f.read()
for line in highscores_line[:5]:
    print(line)
```

And if you want to order and print by descending you could use some sorting algorithm by the number in each line and order the lines before you print them.

reference for sorting - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort#targetText=The%20sort()%20method%20sorts,()%20for%20the%20same%20purpose.

Comment: I believe OP wants the 5 highest scores and they are not sorted in the highscore file

Comment: ok, then how would I order the highscores so that only the top 5 get printed?

Comment: I could write the sorting as well but I think you can handle this yourself ;) read my new answer and just make sure you extract the score itself from the line

Comment: Hi Jowan, if you've found this answer useful I'd appreciate if you might accept the answer (:

Comment: Just gonna say, it doesn't exactly integrate well into my code and I've tried but don't really know how to sort it as it obviously isn't an integer.

Comment: What im saying is, it prints U s e r :

Comment: You gotta extract the integers in your lines (can do with regex but your lines are always the same so regex would be overkill) and what do you mean by it prints user?